# What about OpenEJB? Is it worth it? Any opinions?

Tags: ejb, openejb

I whould like to know some opinions about OpenEJB: we are considering to use it on a new project, but really didn't found many opinions about it.

So, here is my question: how about it? Does it perform well? Is it stable enough for a production environment?

Comment: Also see recent question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332276/comparing-openejb-and-glassfish

Comment: I am not subscribing to its accepted answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We switched to OpenEJB (deployed embedded in our app on Tomcat). Performance tests showed better or not worse results processing our transactions compared to JBoss (transactions include data access, JMS, and servlets). We use ActiveMQ within OpenEJB for JMS. There are no stability problems as of yet - we are still in staging (pre-production) environment though. The documentation is definitely lacking, but not as poor as other embedded choices. Overall, we consider this as a good choice if you run on Tomcat. Deploying it on other application servers turned out to be much more difficult (JBoss, Weblogic, Websphere) but there are not many reasons for this usually (we had few but dropped this after several attempts basically failed).

And as in all open source products: expect lack of support (documentation, troubleshooting, bugs, etc.) to be compensated by free access to sources.

Answer (score 0):

We've had experience with Oracle OAS and JBOSS before. We decided to give OpenEJB a try. We've found out that it is not only very fast but it also much easier to setup and configure, and it has much better defaults.

Currently we implement our own failure measures in the client, so we don't know how they compare for clustering, or other advanced features that we don't use.

We we have to go back and deal with JBOSS in the developer side, we see a drop on productivity, because it takes too long to bootstrap.